# android google analytics: need onreceive()?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm trying to integrate google analytics into an android app using the steps here:
http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

Everything (i.e. screen views, events) is working except for the campaign/referral tracking. Is it enough to update the manifest.xml file? or do I also have to add an onReceive() method?

In the doc, the statement "Only one BroadcastReceiver class can be specified per application" is confusing me. I'm not sure if that means I *have* to implement one or is just a warning about potential conflicts if I already have one implemented.

New to Android, hopefully this is easy to solve...  (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver` is implemented already.
The statement in the docs means that if you want to use Analytics and AdMob referral tracking in one application you need to implement it yourself.
Also keep in mind that it doesn't work in realtime so it may take a day or two until some data shows up.